# base_url not showing desired result inside php tag in codeigniter

Tags: php, html, codeigniter

i am trying to output the image inside php tag through base_url function. it  tried using different combination of quotes but nothing seems to be working here. can any point out exactly where i am doing wrong?

```
$image_url =$this->input->get("image",true);
echo "<img src='base_url('uploads/add_pic/')'.$image_url /> "."<br>";

while in output i am getting

localhost/myproject/online_marketplace_controller/base_url(
```

kindly help me in this regard

Comment: echo "<img src='".base_url('uploads/add_pic/')."'.$image_url /> "."<br>";

Answer (score 2, accepted):

used this type

```
<img src="<?php echo base_url('uploads/add_pic/'.$image_url);?>">
```

OR

```
echo "<img src='".base_url()."uploads/add_pic/".$image_url."'><br>  ";
```

Comment: i want to do it in php tag. for this i have to do it outside php tag

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you set your base url like

```
$config['base_url'] = 'http://localhost/myproject/';
```

Then on your view

```
<img src="<?php echo base_url('uploads/add_pic/' . $this->input->get("image"));?>">
```

Also you can use the html helper https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/helpers/html_helper.html

Make sure you load the helper in the controller or autoload it.

```
<?php

$image_properties = array(
   'src'   => 'uploads/add_pic/' . $this->input->get("image"), 
);

echo img($image_properties);

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use like this

```
<img src="<?php echo base_url();?>uploads/add_pic/<?php echo $image_url; ?>">
```